# How can I reuse the Given Specflow step more efficiently

Tags: c#, specflow, gherkin

I am running out of ideas...
I have this scenario outline:

```
Scenario Outline: Member is assigned to dynamic scope

    Given a dynamic device scope with "<id>", "<name>", "<description>" and "<filter>" exist

    When I post new member assign request with "<member id>", "<first name>", "<last name>" and "<email>"

    Then the response is "<status code>"

    And a member with "<member id>", "<first name>", "<last name>" and "<email>" is added to the dynamic device scope
    Examples:
| no | id | name | desc | filter | member id | first name | last name | email| status code |

| 1  | 01 | name | desc | filter | ee749612  | first      | last    | t1@mail.com| Created |
```

I want to be able to reuse this scenario outline and run it for a dynamic people scope. something like this:

```
Given a **dynamic people** scope with "<id>", "<name>", "<description>" and "<filter>" exist
```

The step behind the Given for dynamic device looks like this:

```
[Given(@"a dynamic device scope with ""(.*)"", ""(.*)"", ""(.*)"" and ""(.*)"" exist")]
public void GivenADynamicDeviceScopeWithAndExist(Guid id, string name, string description, string filter)

    {
        _scopeId = _scenarioSettings.ScopesStorage.BuildTestDynamicDeviceScope(id, name, description, filter);
    }
```

Do you have any idea how can I improve this whitout copying the entire scenario?

Comment: The scenario appears to be less than half a dozen lines. Are you sure it is worth it? Copy-and-paste is more forgivable in Gherkin, because you are describing business processes, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Since the step definition is calling `BuildTestDynamicDeviceScope`, it appears the C# API is specific to the kind of scope being requested. I would recommend creating two separate steps:

```
Given a dynamic device scope...
Given a dynamic people scope...
```

Since a scenario outline is basically pre-processed, try making `device` or `people` in the step a variable in the scenario outline:

```
Scenario Outline: Member is assigned to dynamic scope
    Given a dynamic <scope type> scope with "<id>", "<name>", "<description>" and "<filter>" exist
    When I post new member assign request with "<member id>", "<first name>", "<last name>" and "<email>"
    Then the response is "<status code>"
    And a member with "<member id>", "<first name>", "<last name>" and "<email>" is added to the dynamic device scope

Examples:
    | scope type | no | id | name | desc | filter | member id | first name | last name | email      | status code |
    | device     | 1  | 01 | name | desc | filter | ee749612  | first      | last      | t1@mail.com| Created     |
    | people     | .. | .. | ...  | ...  | ...    | ...       | ...        | ...       | ...        | ...         |
```

The important part being:

```
Given a dynamic <scope type> scope with ...
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Scenario outline tokens do not need to replace step arguments. They can simply replace a part of the step text itself.